# Add shadow to navigation bar iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I'm trying to apply a shadow to the navigation bar, but all my attempts have failed. I found a working solution, but it does not work on ios 15.... Can anyone solve a similar problem and share a working solution

It does not work on ios 15:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.baseGray.cgColor
navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

https://ibb.co/xsHh6wW

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, maybe someone will find it useful

```
func setupShadowNavigationBar() {
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navigationBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
    }
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.baseGray.cgColor
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```